Parse error when I use Col <id> that is greater than 9 in QUERY parameter
I have the following QUERY that I am using with IMPORTRANGE in GoogleSheets.
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("<url>","Sheet name>!A1:I500"), "SELECT Col2, Col3, Col10")

I get the following parse error. Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col10
Appreciate your help.
If I use anything lesser than Col10 like Col9, it seems to work fine.

A:I only includes columns 1 through 9.
